# how can I retrieve a specific JSON data

Tags: json, django

I want to retrieve a specific data after selecting an option form. When I select I got data in JSON format which I can't separated. I have tried obj.purchase_price but got undefined. my following code provide following data

```
           [{"model": "acc.productdetails", "pk": 4, "fields": {"purchase_price": "214.00"}}]
```

I want purchase_price value for my form. Please help me to separate the value. My codes are given bellow

In Views

```
    def priceFilter(request):
        product_id = request.GET.get('product_id',None)

        price = {
                
             'data':serializers.serialize("json",ProductDetails.objects.filter(id=product_id),
              fields=('purchase_price',))
                }

        return JsonResponse(price)
```

In my page, script

```
        <script>
                $("#id_price").change(function () {
                var form = $(this).closest("form");
                $.ajax({
                 url: form.attr("data-validate-price-url"),
                 data: form.serialize(),
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function (price) {
                        if (price.data) {
                        let obj = price.data ;
                        alert(obj) ;

                        }
                       }
                     });

                   });
       </script>
```

I want to show my data here

```
       <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" id="p_price" required>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serializer returns a *string* that is a JSON blob, not a list with dictionaries, etc.

You can wrap the result in a dictionary with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def priceFilter(request):
    product_id = request.GET.get('product_id')
    product = get_object_or_404(Product.objects.only('price'), id=product_id)
    price = {
        'price': product.price
    }
    return JsonResponse(price)
```

In the response, you can retrieve the object with:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.price) {
        let obj = data.price;
        alert(obj) ;
    }
}
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: How can I show price in my input form.  <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" id="p_price" required>

Comment: @Shanzedul: in the JavaScript function with `success:` with `$("#id_price").value(data.price);`